# Accessing dollar sign $0 element in Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, element

I have an element with no name or id attribute I can only access with a dollar sign:

```
console.log($0);
"100"
```

How can I access this from Python Selenium? I'm trying this:

```
my_value=driver.find_element(By.NAME,"$0")
```

But I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"$0"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the element in your console, right-click it and select "Copy full XPath"

then you can use it like

```py
driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR_XPATH_HERE"))
```

[image]